# Mysql Update + SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, combinations

I want to update data table for those who score exam id 1,2 more than 80. I try this

```
UPDATE data
SET column = 'value'
WHERE
(SELECT * FROM exams
WHERE (id = '1' AND score >= 80) AND (id = '2' AND score >= 80));
```

It gives me 0 result. But it should have few hundreds results ANy help??

I think the problem is this:

```
SELECT * FROM exams
WHERE (id = '1' AND score >= 80) AND (id = '2' AND score >= 80)
```

It gives 0 result. How to select those who score more than 80 points for both exam 1 and 2??

Comment: you should provide more info about you data

Comment: tables and columns you're using

Comment: Your query is selecting records where id = '1' AND id = '2' this is always going to be false as it can only have one id value at a time. How to actually correct the query requires more information about the table data I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You query won't work because you're asking for **exams** that have id = 1 **AND** id = 2.

Assuming that id cannot hold two values at the same time, you'll never return any results.

Try this as the basis of your update instead :-

```
SELECT * FROM exams
WHERE score >= 80 AND id IN ( '1','2' )
```

**Edited based on comment :-**

User wants only people who scored more than 80 for **both** exams.  Assuming *personid* is a key to the person who took the exam.

```
SELECT e1.personid FROM
(
   SELECT personid FROM exams  WHERE score >= 80 AND id = '1' 
) e1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT personid FROM exams  WHERE score >= 80 AND id = '2' 
) e2
ON
  e1.personid = e2.personid
```

Comment: erm.. i tested. But an user, he only score exam 1 that above 80, but this query still giving the result. My requirement is, the user must score above 80 for both exam 1 and 2. Either one below 80 should not include

Comment: WOW.. After some adjustment, it works. Thanks. I based on this method though. Really, i cant thank you enough!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your select statement should use an OR:

```
SELECT * FROM exams
WHERE (id = '1' AND score >= 80) OR (id = '2' AND score >= 80)
```

Comment: I think this does not work. The user must meet 2 requirements. Exam 1 and 2 must be above 80. Ur query return exam 1 or exam 2 even the user only score exam 1 above 80

Comment: Gotcha. Paul Alan Taylor has your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM exams
WHERE (id = '1' OR id = '2') AND score >=80
```

Because you cannot have `id ='1'` and `id = '2'` simultaneously the number of values returned in your case is `0`.